# Pagination with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I watched 10+ tutorials but I'm still unable to solve this basic operation.

How do I paginate with puppeteer the Glassdoor page I'm scraping?

Here I am successfully logging into glassdoor(logging details have been replaced with ****), and scraping basic details such as companyName, datePosted etc. visible on the first page:

```
async function scrapeListings(page) {

//navigating to the list of jobs i.e. logging in to Glassdoor
try {
  await page.goto("https://www.glassdoor.co.uk/index.htm");
    await page.click(
      "#SiteNav > nav > div.d-lg-none.d-flex.align-items-center.justify-content-between.px-std.py-xsm.px-md-lg.py-md-std.LockedHomeHeaderStyles__bottomBorder.LockedHomeHeaderStyles__fullWidth > div.d-flex.justify-content-center.order-1.order-md-2.LockedHomeHeaderStyles__flexibleContainer > button",
      { delay: 200 }
    );
    await page.type("#userEmail", "*******", {
      delay: 200,
    });
    await page.type("#userPassword", "*******", { delay: 200 });
    await page.click(".mt-std.d-flex.flex-column.align-items-center", {
      delay: 200,
    });

    await page.waitForNavigation();
    await page.goto(
      "https://www.glassdoor.co.uk/Job/london-internship-jobs-SRCH_IL.0,6_IC2671300_KO7,17_IP1.htm"
    );
  

  const html = await page.content();
  const $ = cheerio.load(html);
  const listings = $("[data-test='jobListing']")
    .map((index, element) => {
      const titleElement = $(element).find(".css-l2wjgv.e1n63ojh0.jobLink");
      const timeElement = $(element).find("[data-test='job-age']");
      const companyName = $(titleElement).text();
    

      const url = "https://www.glassdoor.co.uk" + $(titleElement).attr("href");
      const datePosted = $(timeElement).text();
  

      return { companyName, url, datePosted };
    })
    .get();
  return listings; 
  await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0'})
} catch (erro) {
    console.error(erro);
  }
}
```

In this second part I get url of each job description and scrape a page with more details:

```
async function scrapeJobDescriptions(listings, page) {
  for (var i = 0; i < listings.length; i++) {
    await page.goto(listings[i].url);
    const html = await page.content();
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    // const jobDescription = $(".desc").text();
    const jobDescription = $("#JobDescriptionContainer").html();
    const location = $(".css-f4rs18.css-1e169oc.efy8art2 > div > div > div:nth-child(3)").text()
    const jobSalary = $(".css-1v5elnn.e11nt52q2 .small.css-10zcshf.e1v3ed7e1").text()
    const jobPosition = $(".css-17x2pwl").text();
    const applyLink =
      "https://www.glassdoor.co.uk" +
      $(".css-0.e1h54cx80 a").attr("data-job-url");
    try {
    const companyImage = await page.$eval(
      // ".oc-photo-gallery .photo__10vsfGte img",
      ".css-13u5hxa.epu0oo22 img",
      (img) => img.src
    );
   

    listings[i].jobDescription = jobDescription;
    listings[i].location = location;
    listings[i].jobSalary = jobSalary;
    listings[i].jobPosition = jobPosition;
    listings[i].applyLink = applyLink;
    listings[i].companyImage = companyImage;
    console.log(listings[i].jobDescription);
    const listingModel = new GlassdoorDB(listings[i]);
    await listingModel.save();
    await sleep(1000); //1 second sleep

  
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
}
}
}

async function sleep(miliseconds) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, miliseconds));
}

async function main() {
  await connectToMongoDb();
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const listings = await scrapeListings(page);
  const listingsWithJobDescriptions = await scrapeJobDescriptions(
    listings,
    page
  );
  console.log(listings);
}

main();
```

How can I get to the next page after the first page with 30 results have been scraped?

Comment: Have you tried to go to that page yourself to see how the pagination works? There's gonna be a button or link you click to get to another page. Pagination is usually done throught querystring in the url like `<some-url>?page=1&limit=20`

Comment: Yes, the button I need to press has selector: $('[data-test="pagination-next"]'). But I have no idea how to implement it in this code. I.e. where in my code do I know that all the data from one page has been scraped and now is the time to: await await page.click('[data-test="pagination-next"]')```

Comment: So the big question is - In which part of the code do I add the querysting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the URL pattern for the pagination - as Molda recommended - and instead of awaiting the puppeteer actions then clicking the "next" button: you can `page.goto` to the next ones. E.g.: https://example.net?page=1 etc.

In most paginations, you can retrieve the number of the last page (`el.href.match(/\d+/)`) if there is a "last" button to jump to the very last page.

E.g.:

```js
await page.goto('https://example.net')
const lastPage = await page.evaluate(el => el.href.match(/\d+/), (await page.$$('.pager-last > a'))[0])

for (let i = 0; i < parseInt(lastPage[0]) + 1; i++) {
  try {
    await page.goto('https://example.net?page=' + i)
    // manipulating the DOM
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}
```

On the Glassdoor site you will be able to retrieve the length of the pagination from the following `<div>`:

```html
<div class="cell middle d-none d-md-block py-sm" data-test="page-x-of-y">Page 1 of 17</div>
```

```js
const lastPage = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerText.replace(/page\s\d\sof\s/i, ''), (await page.$$('[data-test="page-x-of-y"]')[0])
```

Comment: Thank you for the extensive explanation, almost there. So far the code along with the glassdoor links is 

`const lastPage = await page.evaluate((el) => el.href.match(/\d+/),
  (await page.$$(".pager-last > a"))[0]
    );
    for (let i = 0; i < parseInt(lastPage[0]) + 1; i++) {
      try {await page.goto('https://www.glassdoor.co.uk/Job/london-internship-jobs-SRCH_IL.0,6_IC2671300_KO7,17_IP${i}.htm?fromAge=30');
        // manipulating the DOM
      } catch (e) {console.error(e); }}`

Comment: I tried implementing it in different parts of the code but it does not work. This is probably caused by having two functions `scrapeListings` and `scrapeJobDescriptions`. Could you recommend in which part of the code should I paste the for loop? (I tried to put it to the `scrapeListings` func or put the two functions within the loop, no success tho.

Comment: Note: the example I gave above is not specific to the different pages of Glassdoor, only the last two snippets are there to give a clue how the same information can be retrieved for the length of the loop etc. so you will need to do the research to place the correct selectors and to align the code for the page.
I am not totally familiar with the site so I may be wrong (looking at it without sign in) but I'd say you can implement it in the `scrapeJobDescriptions` function, there I see the pagination possibility.